# Matrices over a commutative ring as category

Tags: matrices, category-theory

In the book Categories for the working mathematician of Mac Lane:

For each commutative ring $K$, the set $\mathbf{Matr_K}$ of all rectangular matrices with entries in $K$ is a category; the objects are all positive integers m,n,..., and each $m\times n$ matrix $A$ is regarded as an arrow $A:n\rightarrow m$, with composition the usual matrix product.

Does this category contain as much information as $\mathbf{Matr_K}$? Given an arrow, how do I know which matrice it represents?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a bit of misstatement about the objects, which you say "are all positive integers."  Should we not regard the arrow $A:K^n \to K^m$ instead?

Comment: @hardmath In this category, $n$ is an object that can be interpreted as $K^n$.

Comment: What are you asking? The arrows are labelled by matrices, so by definition no information is lost.

Comment: @Mr.Chip I mean, all the information in the category is the objects, the arrows, and how the arrows compose. The name of the objects or arrows are not essential.

Comment: Maybe you mean extra structure you can put on $\mathbf{Matr}_{\mathbf{K}}$ in addition to the category structure?  For example, $\mathbf{Matr}_{\mathbf{K}}$ has a natural structure of *abelian category* since $\operatorname{Hom}(n,m)$ is an abelian group for each $n,m$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I mean, if we just relabel the arrows, then the structure of the category is still preserved. Now if I choose an arrow, can I tell which matrix it comes from?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Technically, as it is defined here it is not abelian, because it doesn't have a zero object.

Comment: Oh, right, I missed that $0$ is not an object of the category.

Comment: Maybe if you add the structure that each $\operatorname{Hom}(n,m)$ is a free $K$-module of dimension $mn$ with a canonical basis, with composition maps being $K$-linear, and satisfying $e_{ij} \cdot e_{i'j'} = \delta_{ji'} e_{ij'}$, then from that additional structure you could recover the matrix representation of any arrow.  (And the labelling of objects could potentially be recovered by the maximum length of a chain of monomorphisms which aren't isomorphisms ending at the object - possibly depending on properties of $K$.)

Comment: Maybe to make the question more precise, are you thinking something like: is there some *categorical property* on arrows (a property defined on all morphisms of all categories which is preserved under equivalence of categories) such that restricted to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Matr}_{\mathbf{K}}}(n,m)$ it is equivalent to $A = \cdot$?

Comment: In that case, I think the answer would be "no" since you could make an equivalence from $\mathbf{Matr}_{\mathbf{K}}$ to itself which corresponds to "changing the basis of a single $n$", which wouldn't in general restrict to the identity on $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Matr}_{\mathbf{K}}}(n, m)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That is what I thought. I guess I'm not happy because this category merely encodes $\mathbf{Matr_K}$ as a set and some additional operation between the elements, but not the elements themselves as matrices.

Comment: @DanielSchepler But can we hope to retrieve the matrix up to some equivalence?

Comment: How is this different from the situation in $\mathbf{Sets}$ where a similar argument shows the exact function can't be recovered as a categorical property of the arrow?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Well ok then!

Comment: I think for example, in the case $K$ is a field, the only information about a matrix you could extract as a categorical property would be its rank.  (Or in the case of $\operatorname{Hom}(n,n)$ and $K$ algebraically complete, possibly the Jordan normal form - or maybe just the Jordan normal form of the nilpotent and $\lambda=1$ parts.)

Comment: @Mr.Chip: I understand the question as: If one forgets those "labels", exactly how much information is lost?

Answer (score 1):

> Given an arrow, how do I know which matri[x] it represents?

To make the composition you describe ("the usual matrix product") well-defined, we must assign a canonical ordered basis to each object $n$ or $K^n$.  The standard ordered basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ would work nicely.

Comment: How do you need canonical bases just to multiply matrices?  I think the point of the example is that $\mathbf{Matr}_{\mathbf{K}}$ isn't immediately defined in terms of functions (even though as you observe, it's easy to see it's equivalent to a full subcategory of the category $\mathbf{Mod}_{\mathbf{K}}$ of $K$-modules).

Comment: I don't need bases to multiply matrices, but I do need bases to "recover" the matrix from a map (arrow) from $K^n$ to $K^m$.  Dropping the objects entirely and working only with arrows amounts to the same thing, where the identity arrows correspond to identity matrices.